# Why does this Machine.Fakes parameter matching throw an exception?

Tags: mspec, machine.fakes

I'm using `Machine.Fakes.NSubstitute` and want to "fake" a return value such that if the input parameter matches a specific value it returns the mock object, otherwise it returns null.

I tried the following:

```
host.WhenToldTo(h => h.GetTenantInstance(Param.Is(new Uri("http://foo.bar"))))
    .Return(new TenantInstance());
```

But it throws the following exception:

> System.InvalidCastException: Unable to cast object of type
>   'System.Linq.Expressions.NewExpression' to type
>   'System.Linq.Expressions.ConstantExpression'.

My current workaround is to do the following:

```
host.WhenToldTo(h => h.GetTenantInstance(Param.IsAny<Uri>()))
    .Return<Uri>(uri => uri.Host == "foo.bar" ? new TenantInstance() : null);
```

Which is a bit smelly.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I see three aspects here:

1. When a method with a reference type return value is called on a mock object and no behavior has been set up for the call, the mock object **will return a mock**. If you want it to return `null` instead, you have to configure that explicitly. Thus, it is not enough to set up

   ```
   host.WhenToldTo(h => h.GetTenantInstance(Param.Is(new Uri("http://foo.bar"))))
       .Return(new TenantInstance());
   ```

   You also have to set up the other case with something like this:

   ```
   host.WhenToldTo(h => h.GetTenantInstance(Param<Uri>.Matches(x => !x.Equals(new Uri("http://foo.bar")))))
       .Return((TenantInstance)null);
   ```

   I find your *"workaround"* solution more elegant than these two setups.
2. When you match a method call argument for equality, there is **no need to use `Param.Is()`**. You can simply set up the behavior with

   ```
   host.WhenToldTo(h => h.GetTenantInstance(new Uri("http://foo.bar")))
       .Return(new TenantInstance());
   ```
3. The fact that you get an exception when using `Param.Is()` here is a **shortcoming of Machine.Fakes**. I see not reason why this should not work. I will correct that at some point and let you know.

Comment: The bug is fixed in version 1.0.4. You will not get an exception even when using `Param.Is()`.